# how to save modified xml file to a worksheet cell using vba

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have loaded an XML content from a cell in a worksheet and after modifying the XML i tried saving the XML file back to a different cell in a work sheet .I am getting an error while doing it

```
Sub XMLTest01()
Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.Dom Document
Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.Dom Document
Dim strXML As String
Strxml = sheets("sheet2").Range("a1") 
xmlDoc.LoadXML(strXML) 
 ---- some logic ----

xmldoc.save ( sheets("sheet2").Range("a1") )
end
```

Please let me know how i can save the modified xml to cell

Comment: Can you edit to share what error you are facing.

Comment: Why do you have a space in `Dom Document` ?

Answer (score 0):

MSXML's [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753769(v=vs.85).aspx) method only works to save a DOM object to an external .xml file, so requires a defined path. Consider saving it to a temp file, then read content in using FSO to a string variable that is later outputted to cell:

```vb
... 
xmldoc.save "C:\Path\To\Temp.xml"

Dim objFSO As Object 
Dim strXML As String 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
strXML = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Path\To\Temp.xml").ReadAll 

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = strXML
```

Or line by line for larger files:

```vb
Dim strXML As String, line As String
Dim fileNo As Integer

fileNo = FreeFile

Open "C:\Path\To\Temp.xml" For Input As #fileNo 
Do While Not EOF(fileNo) 
   Line Input #fileNo, line
   strXML = strXML & line 
Loop
Close #fileNo

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = strXML
```